# Copy / Backup Persistent Store

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nsfilemanager

Normally when I backed up the core data file for my app, I would just copy the .sqlite file to another location while the app was running. But now that journaling (wal) is enabled, this does not work anymore. I cannot see a way for NSPersistentStoreCordinator or NSManagedObjectContext to write a new file. I'm guessing maybe I have 2 methods:

1. - Close the persistent store and opening it again with @{@"journal_mode" : @"DELETE"} and then copy the .sqlite file.
2. Add another persistent store and maybe copy from the original ps to the new one ?

Any better ideas ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Changing the journal mode will eliminate the journal files, so it's simple. I don't know that I'd trust it for your use, though-- because there's no guarantee that Core Data has actually flushed all new changes to the SQLite file. It might be OK, but there might be some in-memory changes that Core Data hasn't written out yet. This is almost certainly safe, but there's a small chance that it won't work right once in a while.

Option 2 would be safer, though more work. I'd create the second persistent store using `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`'s `migratePersistentStore:toURL:options:withType:error:` method (which the docs specifically mention as being useful for "save as" operations). Telling Core Data to create the copy for you should ensure that everything necessary is actually copied. Just *don't do this on your main persistent store coordinator*, because after migration, the PSC drops the reference to the original store object (the file's still there, but it's no longer used by that PSC). The steps would be

1. Create a new migrate-only `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` and add your original persistent store file.
2. Use this new PSC to migrate to a new file URL.
3. Drop all reference to this new PSC, don't use it for anything else.

Comment: Could option 3 be to just copy the SQLite file and the associated journaling files? The journaling files have the same filename as the sqlite file but with different path extensions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How about the persistent store metadata? I've found out I'm loosing it after my *.sqlite database restored on other device. Is it true or my mistake?

Comment: Metadata is stored in the SQLite file in a separate table. You shouldn't need to take any special steps to avoid losing it. However if you lose track of journal files, you can lose all kinds of data, including metadata. If you're losing it somehow, post a question describing what you're doing that causes it to be lost.

Comment: how do I restore from this file?

Comment: Restoring is backing up in reverse, so the steps are the same.

Comment: Thanks. May I know, these day, do you recommend `replacePersistentStore` over `migratePersistentStore`, based on your blog? - https://www.atomicbird.com/blog/core-data-backups-redux/