# Save a copy of sqlite file in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, core-data

I am trying to make a copy of current Core Data database file.

After doing some research, I found that `migratePersistentStore(_:to:options:withType:)` might be useful in this situation, as the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentstorecoordinator/1468927-migratepersistentstore) saying,

> This method is typically used for “Save As” operations.

While the documentation also said,

> **Important**
>
> After invocation of this method, the specified store is removed from the coordinator thus store is no longer a useful reference.

Therefore, I tried to keep the original store reference so that the app can continue working.

Inspired by [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22672386/9148248), I followed [Tom Harrington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43832/tom-harrington) idea:

> 1. Create a new migrate-only `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` and add your original persistent store file.
> 2. Use this new PSC to migrate to a new file URL.
> 3. Drop all reference to this new PSC, don't use it for anything else.

Here's my codes, for sharing backup sqlite file using `UIActivityViewController`:

```
func shareDatabase() {
        let backupFileName = "Backup.sqlite"
        let backupFilePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("Library").appendingPathComponent("Application Support").appendingPathComponent(backupFileName)
        let mainDataPSC = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator
        let migratePSC = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: mainDataPSC.managedObjectModel)
        let origStore = mainDataPSC.persistentStores.first!

        try! migratePSC.migratePersistentStore(origStore, to: backupFilePath, options: [NSSQLitePragmasOption: ["journal_mode": "DELETE"]], withType: NSSQLiteStoreType)

        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [backupFilePath], applicationActivities: nil)
        present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Unfortunately, it still lose reference to the original store after migration, and app is not working normally afterward.

Is this the correct way to make copy of sqlite file?
How can I keep the original reference?

Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't quite do what I meant in that other answer, but in fairness I might not have explained it as clearly as I should have. You're having this problem because you're still migrating `origStore`, so it's still getting removed and is still becoming invalid. Using the new coordinator isn't enough-- you have to be sure to leave the existing Core Data stack alone.

A fuller description of the process is:

1. Create a new `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`-- which you're already doing.
2. Add your persistent store file to the coordinator (your `migratePSC`) by using `addPersistentStore(ofType:configurationName:at:options:)`. This function returns an `NSPersistentStore` object.
3. Use the new coordinator (`migratePSC`) to migrate the new persistent store from step 2 to a new location (`backupFilePath`).

After this, the persistent store from step 2 will be invalid, but you're not using it anywhere else so that doesn't matter. Meanwhile your existing `NSPersistentContainer` and all of its properties are untouched and your app continues to work.

Comment: It works. I added a store using `let backupPersistentStore = try! migratePSC.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: mainDataPSC.persistentStores.first!.url!, options: nil)` and migrate this `backupPersistentStore` to `backupFilePath`. All seem functional.