# Core Data migratePersistentStore crash with perform/performAndWait

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, core-data

I'm attempting to use `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.migratePersistentStore(_:to:options:withType:)` to move a persistent store from one location to another, using an [approach like this](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/moving-core-data-files/). (My overall goal is to create a backup, so I'm also [drawing on the Ole Begemann's work here](https://oleb.net/blog/2018/03/core-data-sqlite-backup/), which is in turn inspired by a [previous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670273/copy-backup-persistent-store/22672386#22672386), but the problem I encounter is the same in both cases.)

```
let sourceStore = ... // NSPersistentStore
let backupFileURL = ... // URL
try self.migratePersistentStore(sourceStore, to: backupFileURL, options: [:], withType: NSSQLiteStoreType)
```

When calling `migratePersistentStore`, Core Data loads objects into memory, triggering a call to `awakeFromFetch()` on each one. That uses some memory, no surprise, but not necessarily a big deal in this case.

However, if `awakeFromFetch()` happens to do something that uses `NSManagedObjectContext.perform` or `NSManagedObjectContext.performAndWait`, the app crashes while moving the persistent store with an error like this one:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can only use -performBlock: on an NSManagedObjectContext that was created with a queue.'
```

As far as I can tell, the crash occurs because during the move/migration, `awakeFromFetch()` is being called in an NSManagedObjectContext that uses the deprecated `confinementConcurrencyType` and calls to perform/performAndWait aren't permitted on with that concurrency type.

(Here's a super simple example `awakeFromFetch()` that I'm using as a demonstration:)

```
public override func awakeFromFetch() {
    super.awakeFromFetch()
    managedObjectContext?.perform {
        print("Hello, world!")
    }
}
```

I could theoretically work around this by checking the context's concurrency type and only wrap calls in perform/performAndWait if it's not a confinement context, but that seems both unwieldy and out of line with best practices.

Does anyone have a recommendation for how to handle this? Is there a way to prompt `migratePersistentStore` to use a different concurrency type?

Comment: As far as I understand the perform blocks are required when any context is added to a queue other than the main queue, so perhaps it is worth investigating the use of `NSOperation`? An aside... Is your project capable (based on iOS target) of using the newer convenience methods for `NSPersistentContainer` such as [`newBackgroundContext`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentcontainer/1640581-newbackgroundcontext)?

Comment: @andrewbuilder I know there are some ways I could work around the issue, but I'm most interested in figuring out why this scenario is arising in the first place. Specifically, why does a call to `migratePersistentStore` seem to create a context with a deprecated concurrency type, and what's the best way for apps to manage that situation? Avoiding widely-used API like perform/performAndWait seems like it can't be the only answer, even if it might be effective.